# what does flags -o and -L means in bash

Tags: bash, file

I have such part of bash script

if [ ! -e $f -o -L $f ] ; then

where $f is filename

I know that -e means "exist" but I cannot find what -o and -L means

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Translated to programmer English, it's "`if` the file (`$f`) does not exist (`-e`) or (`-o`) the file (`$f`) is a [symbolic link](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Symbolic_link) (`-L`), then ..."

`man bash` has more details.

Answer (score 1):

-o : True if shell option "OPTIONNAME" is enabled.

-L : True if FILE exists and is a symbolic link.

http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, this is interesting. We have first the definition of the `[` builtin:

```
`EXPR1 -o EXPR2'
      True if either EXPR1 or EXPR2 is true.
```

... and then we have the definition of Conditional expression which are used for this builtin:

```
`-o OPTNAME'
     True if the shell option OPTNAME is enabled.  The list of options
     appears in the description of the `-o' option to the `set' builtin
     (*note The Set Builtin::).
```

Obviously here the intended meaning is the first one (if the file does not exist or is a link), but I'm not sure why this works.